# How to submit a form with some hidden information in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a method post **add** from controller and passed two parameters (two IDs) by a link to a form in which the user can fill other information. I want the 'Submit' button to create an object which would take two IDs as its attributes.

How can I do this?

Comment: please show the code you have tried to achieve this with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use hiddent_field tag for this

```
<%= f.hidden_field :id_1, value: "ID" %>
```